# How to automate button with javascript query for facebook?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, console

I am trying to automate below facebook donate button with javascript query

[Screenshot of Donate button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2fqj.png)

```
document.getElementById('pay_button').click();
```

but the problem is that i get a response as

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
```

which means there's no ID with such but facebook sourcecode is showing **data-testid="pay_button"**. Can anybody help me how can automate this donate button, maybe I am using wrong class id? I tried using other class but all i am getting is null, how can i identify right class id in this case?

```
    <div class="_39ge">
   <div class="_39gi">
      <button data-testid="pay_button" type="button" aria-disabled="false" class="_271k _1qjd _7tvm _7tv2 _7tv4" style="width: 100%; letter-spacing: normal; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 34px; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(0, 164, 0); border-color: rgb(0, 164, 0); height: 36px; padding-left: 19px; padding-right: 19px; border-radius: 2px;">
         <div class="_43rl">
            <div data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-display="overflow" class="_43rm">
               <div class="_304_ clearfix">
                  <div class="_ohe lfloat">
                     <div class="_2pis">Donate</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="_ohf rfloat">
                     <div class="_2pii"><span>$55.00</span></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

[Screenshot from FB View Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwkMY.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I do not see any elements that have the ID of `pay_button`. If the element does not exists, you won't be able to bind an event to it.

Comment: Can i consider data-testid as ID? Is there any way i can bind it if not?

Comment: what is the use case for this? why would anyone want to automate this? also, those things are usually not allowed on facebook. rule of thumb: if there is api, it is not allowed.

Comment: @aruzmeister no. The ID attribute is the ID attribute. You cannot use another attribute as the ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a different selector.

```js
$(function() {
  $("[data-testid='pay_button']").click(function() {
    console.log("Button Clicked.");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="_39ge">
  <div class="_39gi">
    <button data-testid="pay_button" type="button" aria-disabled="false" class="_271k _1qjd _7tvm _7tv2 _7tv4" style="width: 100%; letter-spacing: normal; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 34px; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(0, 164, 0); border-color: rgb(0, 164, 0); height: 36px; padding-left: 19px; padding-right: 19px; border-radius: 2px;">
         <div class="_43rl">
            <div data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-display="overflow" class="_43rm">
               <div class="_304_ clearfix">
                  <div class="_ohe lfloat">
                     <div class="_2pis">Donate</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="_ohf rfloat">
                     <div class="_2pii"><span>$55.00</span></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is an attribute selector, [see more](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am not able to run in my console? You mean something like this 
`document.getElementById("[data-testid='pay_button']").click();`

Comment: @aruzmeister No I do not mean that. You cannot 'get element by ID' in that way. If you're looking for a JavaScript method, see more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll